# What is the difference between the basis of a vector space and the basis of the kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for some clarification on what a 'basis' means for various sets of vectors. In particular the difference, between the basis of a set of vectors and the basis of the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Basis** $B$ of a **Vector Space** $V\ $is any set of vectors in that Vector Space that satisfies these two conditions:

$1)\ $ $V=\text{Span} (B)$

This basically means that every vector in $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in $B$.

$2)\ $ $B$ is $\text{Linearly Independent}$

Loosely put, this states that every vector in $B$ is making its own unique contribution and can not be expressed as a linear combination of the remaining vectors in $B$.

---

> The way I like to think about it is that every Vector Space consists
>   of several vectors, but its basis is the **smallest possible** subset
>   of those several vectors which can be used to express **every single
>   vector in that Vector Space**.

The **Kernel** is a specific kind of Vector Space and everything that I have mentioned above about general Vector Spaces also applies to the Kernel in particular.

Answer (score 5):

Given a linear transformation $T : V \to W$, its kernel $\text{Ker}(T)$ **is** a vector space: $\text{Ker}(T)$  is a subspace of the vector space $V$; and every subspace of a vector space is a vector space in its own right.

So, the definition of basis for a vector space can be applied *as it is written* to the vector space $\text{Ker}(T)$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. Vector spaces can have bases (except in some cases they can't, which is a different discussion entirely), and that's that. Note that this also goes for subspaces of larger vector spaces.

A kernel (of a linear transformation) *is* a vector space. It's a subspace of the domain (of that linear transformation). And therefore it can have a basis just as much as any other vector space.

Sets of vectors which are not vector spaces do not have bases.